# Unable to start WildFly-10.0.0.Final on Eclipse neon 3 and NetBeans 8.0.2

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, wildfly

I have a problem starting wildfly-10.0.0.Final on Eclipse(Neon 3) and NetBeans(8.0.2).

I've tried searching if there is another process occupying the port 8080 but that's not the case.

Below is the errors that appeared when I started wildfly on both IDEs.

If possible, please explain the solution in simpler terms as I am still a beginner in this.

```
Calling "C:\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\bin\standalone.conf.bat"
"JAVA_OPTS already set in environment; overriding default settings with values: -Xms128m -Xmx512m -server -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost,127.0.0.1,ASUS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true"
Setting JAVA property to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java"
===============================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: "C:\wildfly-10.0.0.Final"

  JAVA: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java"

  JAVA_OPTS: "-Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms128m -Xmx512m -server -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost,127.0.0.1,ASUS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true"

===============================================================================

11:07:37,454 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.5.1.Final
11:07:37,735 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.6.Final
11:07:37,826 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 10.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.0.10.Final) starting
11:07:40,109 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
11:07:40,135 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-8) XNIO version 3.3.4.Final
11:07:40,146 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-8) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.3.4.Final
11:07:40,289 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 36) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
11:07:40,394 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 41) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
11:07:40,466 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 40) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 8 core threads with 64 task threads based on your 4 available processors
11:07:40,661 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (WildFly/IronJacamar 1.3.2.Final)
11:07:40,672 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
11:07:40,999 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) WFLYTX0013: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make sure it is unique.
11:07:41,011 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
11:07:41,085 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
11:07:41,092 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
11:07:41,109 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=4.9.4.Final
11:07:41,147 INFO  [org.wildfly.iiop.openjdk] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 42) WFLYIIOP0001: Activating IIOP Subsystem
11:07:41,260 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
11:07:41,390 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
11:07:41,432 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
11:07:41,464 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.3.15.Final starting
11:07:41,518 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.3.15.Final starting
11:07:41,751 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path 'C:\wildfly-10.0.0.Final/welcome-content' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']
11:07:41,957 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 64 (per class), which is derived from thread worker pool sizing.
11:07:41,959 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEJB0482: Strict pool mdb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 16 (per class), which is derived from the number of CPUs on this host.
11:07:42,749 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\standalone\deployments
11:07:42,765 INFO  [org.wildfly.iiop.openjdk] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYIIOP0009: CORBA ORB Service started
11:07:42,844 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.corba._DEFAULT_.rpc.transport] (MSC service thread 1-7) "IOP00410216: (COMM_FAILURE) Unable to create listener thread on the specified port: 3528": org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 216  completed: No
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.createListenerFailed(ORBUtilSystemException.java:2632)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.createListenerFailed(ORBUtilSystemException.java:2651)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelAcceptorImpl.initialize(SocketOrChannelAcceptorImpl.java:164)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.CorbaTransportManagerImpl.getAcceptors(CorbaTransportManagerImpl.java:217)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.CorbaTransportManagerImpl.addToIORTemplate(CorbaTransportManagerImpl.java:235)
    at com.sun.corba.se.spi.oa.ObjectAdapterBase.initializeTemplate(ObjectAdapterBase.java:122)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.oa.poa.POAImpl.initialize(POAImpl.java:404)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.oa.poa.POAImpl.makeRootPOA(POAImpl.java:272)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.oa.poa.POAFactory$1.evaluate(POAFactory.java:205)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orbutil.closure.Future.evaluate(Future.java:46)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.LocalResolverImpl.resolve(LocalResolverImpl.java:40)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.CompositeResolverImpl.resolve(CompositeResolverImpl.java:45)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orb.ORBImpl.resolve_initial_references(ORBImpl.java:1169)
    at org.wildfly.iiop.openjdk.service.CorbaPOAService.start(CorbaPOAService.java:156)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:67)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.DefaultSocketFactoryImpl.createServerSocket(DefaultSocketFactoryImpl.java:83)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelAcceptorImpl.initialize(SocketOrChannelAcceptorImpl.java:161)
    ... 16 more

11:07:42,870 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.iiop-openjdk.poa-service.rootpoa: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.iiop-openjdk.poa-service.rootpoa: WFLYIIOP0098: Failed to resolve initial reference RootPOA
    at org.wildfly.iiop.openjdk.service.CorbaPOAService.start(CorbaPOAService.java:158)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 216  completed: No
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.createListenerFailed(ORBUtilSystemException.java:2632)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.createListenerFailed(ORBUtilSystemException.java:2651)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelAcceptorImpl.initialize(SocketOrChannelAcceptorImpl.java:164)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.CorbaTransportManagerImpl.getAcceptors(CorbaTransportManagerImpl.java:217)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.CorbaTransportManagerImpl.addToIORTemplate(CorbaTransportManagerImpl.java:235)
    at com.sun.corba.se.spi.oa.ObjectAdapterBase.initializeTemplate(ObjectAdapterBase.java:122)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.oa.poa.POAImpl.initialize(POAImpl.java:404)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.oa.poa.POAImpl.makeRootPOA(POAImpl.java:272)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.oa.poa.POAFactory$1.evaluate(POAFactory.java:205)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orbutil.closure.Future.evaluate(Future.java:46)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.LocalResolverImpl.resolve(LocalResolverImpl.java:40)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.CompositeResolverImpl.resolve(CompositeResolverImpl.java:45)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orb.ORBImpl.resolve_initial_references(ORBImpl.java:1169)
    at org.wildfly.iiop.openjdk.service.CorbaPOAService.start(CorbaPOAService.java:156)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:67)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.DefaultSocketFactoryImpl.createServerSocket(DefaultSocketFactoryImpl.java:83)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelAcceptorImpl.initialize(SocketOrChannelAcceptorImpl.java:161)
    ... 16 more

11:07:42,907 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
11:07:42,934 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-5) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Mahou' 8.1.0.Final
11:07:42,928 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-4) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Mahou' 8.1.0.Final
11:08:01,207 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service org.wildfly.io.worker.default: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service org.wildfly.io.worker.default: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: XNIO001001: No XNIO provider found
    at org.xnio.Xnio.doGetInstance(Xnio.java:238)
    at org.xnio.Xnio.getInstance(Xnio.java:193)
    at org.wildfly.extension.io.WorkerService.start(WorkerService.java:51)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    ... 3 more

11:08:01,207 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.worker: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.worker: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: XNIO001001: No XNIO provider found
    at org.xnio.Xnio.doGetInstance(Xnio.java:238)
    at org.xnio.Xnio.getInstance(Xnio.java:193)
    at org.jboss.as.server.mgmt.ManagementWorkerService.start(ManagementWorkerService.java:51)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    ... 3 more

11:08:01,221 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("core-service" => "management"),
    ("management-interface" => "http-interface")
]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.worker" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.worker: Failed to start service
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: XNIO001001: No XNIO provider found"},
    "WFLYCTL0288: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
        "Services that were unable to start:" => [
            "jboss.remoting.endpoint.management",
            "jboss.remoting.endpoint.management.channel.management",
            "jboss.remoting.management.channel.registry",
            "jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http",
            "jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http.shutdown"
        ],
        "Services that may be the cause:" => [
            "jboss.http-upgrade-registry.default",
            "jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.http-remoting-connector"
        ]
    }
}
11:08:01,226 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "io"),
    ("worker" => "default")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"org.wildfly.io.worker.default" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service org.wildfly.io.worker.default: Failed to start service
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: XNIO001001: No XNIO provider found"}}
11:08:01,233 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "jmx"),
    ("remoting-connector" => "jmx")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0288: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
    "Services that were unable to start:" => ["jboss.jmx.remoting-connector-ref"],
    "Services that may be the cause:" => [
        "jboss.http-upgrade-registry.default",
        "jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.http-remoting-connector"
    ]
}}
11:08:01,295 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("subsystem" => "remoting")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0288: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
    "Services that were unable to start:" => ["org.wildfly.remoting.endpoint"],
    "Services that may be the cause:" => [
        "jboss.http-upgrade-registry.default",
        "jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.http-remoting-connector"
    ]
}}
11:08:01,298 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "naming"),
    ("service" => "remote-naming")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0288: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
    "Services that were unable to start:" => ["jboss.naming.remote"],
    "Services that may be the cause:" => [
        "jboss.http-upgrade-registry.default",
        "jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.http-remoting-connector"
    ]
}}
11:08:01,300 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "undertow"),
    ("server" => "default-server")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0288: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
    "Services that were unable to start:" => ["jboss.undertow.server.default-server"],
    "Services that may be the cause:" => [
        "jboss.http-upgrade-registry.default",
        "jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.http-remoting-connector"
    ]
}}
11:08:01,303 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "undertow"),
    ("server" => "default-server"),
    ("http-listener" => "default")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0288: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
    "Services that were unable to start:" => ["jboss.undertow.listener.default"],
    "Services that may be the cause:" => [
        "jboss.http-upgrade-registry.default",
        "jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.http-remoting-connector"
    ]
}}
11:08:01,306 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "undertow"),
    ("server" => "default-server"),
    ("host" => "default-host")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0288: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
    "Services that were unable to start:" => ["jboss.undertow.server.default-server.default-host"],
    "Services that may be the cause:" => [
        "jboss.http-upgrade-registry.default",
        "jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.http-remoting-connector"
    ]
}}
11:08:01,310 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "undertow"),
    ("server" => "default-server"),
    ("host" => "default-host"),
    ("location" => "/")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0288: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
    "Services that were unable to start:" => ["jboss.undertow.server.default-server.default-host.location./"],
    "Services that may be the cause:" => [
        "jboss.http-upgrade-registry.default",
        "jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.http-remoting-connector"
    ]
}}
11:08:01,313 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "undertow"),
    ("server" => "default-server"),
    ("host" => "default-host"),
    ("filter-ref" => "server-header")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0288: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
    "Services that were unable to start:" => ["jboss.undertow.server.default-server.default-host.filter-ref.server-header"],
    "Services that may be the cause:" => [
        "jboss.http-upgrade-registry.default",
        "jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.http-remoting-connector"
    ]
}}
11:08:01,353 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "undertow"),
    ("server" => "default-server"),
    ("host" => "default-host"),
    ("filter-ref" => "x-powered-by-header")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0288: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
    "Services that were unable to start:" => ["jboss.undertow.server.default-server.default-host.filter-ref.x-powered-by-header"],
    "Services that may be the cause:" => [
        "jboss.http-upgrade-registry.default",
        "jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.http-remoting-connector"
    ]
}}
11:08:01,355 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "messaging-activemq"),
    ("server" => "default")
]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.messaging-activemq.default is missing [jboss.http-upgrade-registry.default]"],
    "WFLYCTL0288: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
        "Services that were unable to start:" => ["jboss.messaging-activemq.default.jms.manager"],
        "Services that may be the cause:" => [
            "jboss.http-upgrade-registry.default",
            "jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.http-remoting-connector"
        ]
    }
}
11:08:01,357 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("subsystem" => "iiop-openjdk")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.iiop-openjdk.poa-service.rootpoa" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.iiop-openjdk.poa-service.rootpoa: WFLYIIOP0098: Failed to resolve initial reference RootPOA
    Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 216  completed: No
    Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind"},
    "WFLYCTL0288: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
        "Services that were unable to start:" => [
            "jboss.iiop-openjdk.naming-service",
            "jboss.iiop-openjdk.poa-service.irpoa",
            "jboss.iiop-openjdk.poa-service.namingpoa"
        ],
        "Services that may be the cause:" => [
            "jboss.http-upgrade-registry.default",
            "jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.http-remoting-connector"
        ]
    }
}
11:08:01,359 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("subsystem" => "jsr77")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0288: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
    "Services that were unable to start:" => ["jboss.jsr77.ejb"],
    "Services that may be the cause:" => [
        "jboss.http-upgrade-registry.default",
        "jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.http-remoting-connector"
    ]
}}
11:08:01,361 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("subsystem" => "webservices")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0288: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
    "Services that were unable to start:" => ["jboss.ws.config"],
    "Services that may be the cause:" => [
        "jboss.http-upgrade-registry.default",
        "jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.http-remoting-connector"
    ]
}}
11:08:01,362 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "undertow"),
    ("servlet-container" => "default")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0288: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
    "Services that were unable to start:" => ["jboss.undertow.servlet-container.default"],
    "Services that may be the cause:" => [
        "jboss.http-upgrade-registry.default",
        "jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.http-remoting-connector"
    ]
}}
11:08:01,405 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("subsystem" => "ejb3")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0288: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
    "Services that were unable to start:" => [
        "jboss.ejb.default-local-ejb-receiver-service",
        "jboss.ejb3.ejbClientContext.default",
        "jboss.ejb3.localEjbReceiver.value"
    ],
    "Services that may be the cause:" => [
        "jboss.http-upgrade-registry.default",
        "jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.http-remoting-connector"
    ]
}}
11:08:01,447 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "ejb3"),
    ("service" => "remote")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.ejb3.connector is missing [jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.http-remoting-connector]"]}
11:08:01,563 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.http-upgrade-registry.default (missing) dependents: [service jboss.messaging-activemq.default] 
      service jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.http-remoting-connector (missing) dependents: [service jboss.ejb3.connector] 
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service org.wildfly.io.worker.default: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service org.wildfly.io.worker.default: Failed to start service
      service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.worker: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.worker: Failed to start service
      service jboss.iiop-openjdk.poa-service.rootpoa: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.iiop-openjdk.poa-service.rootpoa: WFLYIIOP0098: Failed to resolve initial reference RootPOA

11:08:02,021 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0063: Http management interface is not enabled
11:08:02,022 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0054: Admin console is not enabled
11:08:02,022 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: WildFly Full 10.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.0.10.Final) started (with errors) in 24977ms - Started 247 of 578 services (29 services failed or missing dependencies, 385 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

Comment: Where did your `standalone/configuration/standalone.xml` file come from? It's certainly not standard - it has IIOP enabled in it (which is failing to start because of a port conflict on 3528). Can you try with the original version of this file?

Comment: @Steve C all the components are extracted from the wildfly version 10.0.0.Final that i downloaded from the official website. As far as i can remember, i didn't change anything on the files...anyway, is it possible to solve the problem by fixing the "standalone.xml" file or by killing the process that caused the port conflict? i'm still quite blurry about this.

Comment: I would try to revert to the original `standalone.xml` configuration file for now. But you still need to get to the bottom of the port 3528 clash because it might be an orphaned copy of WildFly that is still running or even an old copy of JBoss AS.